# Wordpress every page is 404 not found including admin resources

Tags: php, permalinks

Haven't changed anything on my wordpress in about a year. Suddenly every page is 404 not found, including the admin dashboard.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did your host change the PHP version on you? You could open a support ticket, they might at least be able to get you into your admin.